# Evaluate the limit (if it exists) $\{(\frac{n^3+4n-5}{n^6+2n^2-3},n-7[\frac{n}{7}])\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> $$\left\{\frac{n^3+4n-5}{n^6+2n^2-3},n-7\left[\frac{n}{7}\right]\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$
>
> where $\left[\frac{n}{7}\right]$ is the floor and ceiling function

The sequence converges if each element convarges so:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^3+4n-5}{n^6+2n^2-3}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{n^3}{n^6}+\frac{4n}{n^6}+\frac{-5}{n^6}}{\frac{n^6}{n^6}+\frac{2n^2}{n^6}+\frac{-3}{n^6}}=0$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n-7\left[\frac{n}{7}\right]=\infty\cdot \infty=\infty$$

So $$\left\{\left(\frac{n^3+4n-5}{n^6+2n^2-3},n-7\left[\frac{n}{7}\right]\right)\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\{0,\infty\}$$

And therefore there is not limit?

Comment: Is it the floor function or the ceiling function?

Comment: $\lbrace0,\infty\rbrace$ is a limit. @Cm7F7Bb  I think it is the rounding function.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb it returns a integers, if is less than $0.5$ it is a floor function else it is celling, I do not know the name of this function

Comment: @nicomezi I am not sure in the this part but $n-7$ goes to infinity as n goes and so does $[\frac{n}{7}]$

Comment: @gbox The floor function and the ceiling function have precise definitions. They are two similar but different functions (see [floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)).

Comment: Rewrite your question then, i thought it was $n-(7\times[\frac{n}{7}])$

Comment: @nicomezi you are right!

Comment: Also why the $_{n=1}^\infty$ that sounds like a sum,not a limit,and how do you define $\{a,b\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remainder-like function
$$
n-7\left[\frac n7\right]
$$
cycles among the values $\{0,1,2,3,-3,-2,-1\}$. Since one of the components does not converge, the sequence of pairs does not converge.

Comment: The only way is to insert random values of $n$?

Comment: Or just $n={1,2,3,..,7}$? I am trying to think about the general case let say that I had $425$ and not $7$

Comment: @gbox: It was my, perhaps mistaken, understanding from your comment that $\left[x\right]=\left\lfloor x+\frac12\right\rfloor$ ([floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)).

Comment: We don't insert random values of $n$, but we look at the sequence by inserting arbitrarily large values of $n$; however, the values of $n-7\left[\frac n7\right]$ do not converge, but cycle as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ok, but you found what are the numbers that it cycle around $-3 \leq L\leq 3$ is it finding a general pattern?

Comment: Cycling means that consecutive terms take on these values in order. For example, for $n=7000,7001,7002,7003,7003,7004,7005,7006,7007,7008,7009,7010,7011,7012,7013,\dots$, we get $n-7\left[\frac n7\right]=0,1,2,3,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,-3,-2,-1,\dots$